# The Contents of the title bar are not aligning

Tags: html, css

The Contents Of the bar in the page above are not aligning.

I am trying to get them in 1 line, but they aren't aligning.

Here's the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xgvqzhmh/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="f">

            <section class="wrapper">

              <section class="material-design-hamburger">
                <button class="material-design-hamburger__icon">
                  <span class="material-design-hamburger__layer"></span>
                </button>
              </section>

              <section class="menu menu--off">
                <div>Android's Material Design Hamburger Animation</div>
              </section>

            </section>          
        </div>
        <div class="type">
            <div class="daily">Daily</div>
            <div class="dropdown"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="last"><img src="../Images/ic_action_overflow.png" width="35px" ></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: fab is completely different, it isnt related to the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (https://jsfiddle.net/xgvqzhmh/5/):

```
.header{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #26A69A;
  -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}
.hamburger{
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 2%;
}
.type{
  width: 88%;
}
.daily{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #90CAF9;
  width: 80px;
}
.last{
  width: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.f, .type, .last {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Nope,not working. I wanted it to remain in a straight horizontal line

Comment: No it's working, the problem is however, that your ".type" div is set to 88% and pushes the image to its right down when the available screen space is not wide enough.

Comment: Try the code above, I've accounted for the middle div (".type") to change it's width responsively.

Comment: Nevermind, I Got It Thanks A Lot. Actually i had another css rule that didnt changed the width of the button. Thank